# Different versions of Git on Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: macos, git

I guess Git on my macbook was of version 1.8.4, because I tried

```
git --version
git version 1.8.4

echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

whereis git
/usr/bin/git
```

later I try to upgrade the latest version of Git to 2.0.1, I download and install from

http://git-scm.com/download/mac

Since this installer installs Git to `/usr/local/git`, and append the path to `$PATH`, so now

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

I also replace the binary file to `/usr/bin/` by

```
sudo cp /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/bin/
```

And I logged out and logged in back, but found the following strange situation:

```
/usr/bin/git --version
git version 2.0.1

git --version
git version 1.8.4

whereis git
/usr/bin/git
```

Where does my mac os look for when I type `git --version`? Where is my previous version 1.8.4 located and how can I delete it and replace it with my new version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to use another version of git would be to put it first in the path. Edit the file that appends `/usr/local/git/bin` to the path so that it prepends it instead.

Most likely there is something like the following in either your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin"
```

Change it to:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
```

---

BTW, `sudo cp /usr/local/git/bin/git /usr/bin/` is probably not a good idea, as other software may expect the default version to be there. A software update may also replace it.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution would work but I want to figure out where does my mac os look for when I type `git --version`, why it still shows version 1.8.4 while actual binary `/usr/bin/git` has been replaced?

Comment: For those wondering how to change the profile, this article helps http://hathaway.cc/post/69201163472/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac